# how to merge old and new state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working with arrays. I want to combine old and new array in one state, without deleting old one

```
    const [lessons, setLessons] = useState([''])
    setLessons([...lessons, ...lessons2])
```

i've tried this, but old state keeps deleting

Comment: depending on where you are using `setLessons` you may have memoized or be getting an old value for lessons. The easiest way to get around this is to use the function syntax for `setLessons` to get the current value at the time of setting the state. i.e. `setLessons(currentValue => [...currentValue, ...newLessons])`

Comment: this is actually an asnwer, thank you!